# Why is my ArrayList not reflecting updates after adding a new object to it?

Tags: java, arraylist, fxml, scenebuilder

I currently working on a food menu that has a GUI.

For this purpose, my ArrayList is created as follows in my Dish class:

```
public static List<Dish> getDishes() {
        List<Dish> myMenu = new ArrayList<Dish>();
        myMenu.add(new Dish("Fried Rice", "Rice, Sesame Oil", 10, true, true));
        myMenu.add(new Dish("Sushi Roll", "Rice, Seaweed, Salmon", 5, false, false));
        myMenu.add(new Dish("Pancake", " Egg, Flour, Vanilla Essence", 8, true, false));
        myMenu.add(new Dish("Omelette", " Egg, Tomato, Mushroom, Onion", 8, false, true));
        return myMenu;
    }
```

Now, I'm working on creating an 'add' button that allows the user to input various dish properties. After the user completes the form and hits the 'add' button, a new Dish object is supposed to be added to the ArrayList. This is located in my DishController class which is linked to fxml.

```
    @FXML 
    public void userClickedCreate(ActionEvent event){
        //reading and assinging inputs to var from gui
        String inputDishName = txtCreateDishName.getText();
        String inputDishIngredients = txtCreateDishIngredients.getText();

        //adding new dish object using inputs to arraylist
        Dish.getDishes().add(new Dish(inputDishName, inputDishIngredients, 0, false, false));
        
        //testing if arraylist has been updated succesfully
        List<Dish> myDishes = Dish.getDishes();
        System.out.println(myDishes); 
    }
```

Though I don't receive any errors when proceeding to run the code, when I hit the 'add' button, the printed array list doesn't reflect the new dish. I was hoping to find a way to resolve this.

The output of my program looks like this (the first print statement is before hitting the 'add' button while the second is after hitting the button):

```
[Fried Rice, Sushi Roll, Pancake, Omelette]
[Fried Rice, Sushi Roll, Pancake, Omelette]
```

Comment: `List<Dish> myDishes = Dish.getDishes();` is returning a brand new List.  Suggest you keep the List as a field.

Comment: I've replaced it with ` System.out.println(Dish.getDishes()); ` but nothing changes still.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain clearly enough for you.  The method `getDishes` **is returning a brand new List. Suggest you keep the List as a field.**

Comment: Inside the `getDishes()` method, you have `List<Dish> myMenu = new ArrayList<>();`. Think about what that does and why that would mean changes to the list are not persisted between calls to `getDishes()`.